# Prove that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $E$ if and only if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^nm(\{x\in E:f(x)\geq2^n\})<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Question**: Let $E$ be a finite measure space and let $f$ be a nonnegative function on $E$.  Prove that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $E$ if and only if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^nm(\{x\in E:f(x)\geq2^n\})<\infty$.

**My Thoughts and Attempt**: For the forward direction, if $f$ is integrable on $E$, then $\int_Ef(x)<\infty$.  Consider two sets $A=m(\{x\in E:f(x)\geq2^n\})$ and $B=m(\{x\in E:f(x)<2^n\})$.  Then, $\int_Ef=\int_Af+\int_Bf$.  Since $\int_Ef<\infty$, then, in particular, $\int_Af<\infty$, and so by Markov we get: $2^nm(A)\leq2^n\frac{1}{2^n}\int f(x)<\infty$

For the other direction, suppose $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^nm(\{x\in E:f(x)\geq2^n\})<\infty$.  So, $\int_Ef=\int_Af+\int_Bf$, and by our hypothesis, we know $\int_Af<\infty$.  So, our only concern is about $\int_Bf$..... and this is where I am getting stuck...  Any help, suggestions, etc. are greatly appreciated.  Also, please let me know if I have any errors in the forward direction.  Thank you!

Comment: Your $A$ and $B$ depend on $n$,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need $f$ to be measurable.

Let $C_n=\{x:f(x)\ge 2^n\}$ and consider the indicator function $I_{C_n}$. Define
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^nI_{C_n}(x).$$
Then
$$\int_E g=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^nm(C_n).$$
So you want to show $\int_Ef<\infty$ iff $\int_E g<\infty$.

If $2^N\le f(x)<2^{N+1}$ then $g(x)=1+2+4+\cdots+2^N=2^{N+1}-1$. If $f(x)<1$ then
$g(x)=0$. Therefore $f(x)\le g(x)+1$ and $f(x)\ge g(x)/2$. These inequalities
show that if $\int_Eg$ is finite then so is $\int_Ef$ and *vice versa*.